# Why am I getting a segmentation error for an AArch64 Linux hello world program?

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, arm64

I ran this program to print "Hello World" in assembly, then sent it to the Linux server. The program compiles correctly, but then gives me a segmentation error when I try to run the code. Any ideas?

```
// Program 2:  Hello World
// A program that prints "Hello World!" to the standard output
// (terminal monitor)

.global _start
.text
_start:

    // code for writing message to stdout
    ldr x8, #64    // set register x8 with syscall number for write command
    mov x0, #1     // set register x0 with the file descriptor number
    adr x1, hello_String    // set register x1 with the address of the string
    mov x2, x1    // set register x2 with the string length
    svc #0x80      // make supervisory call to the OS

    // code for exiting the program
    mov x8, #93    // set register x8 with syscall number for exit command
    mov x0, #0     // set register x0 with return value (=0 for no errors)
    svc #0x80      // make supervisory call to the OS

.data
hello_string: .ascii "Hello World!\n"
// end of program
```

Comment: You have to use `.asciiz` to make a null-terminated string.

Comment: I believe you want `svc #0`. Also string length is not `mov x2, x1`. Try `mov x2, #13` instead.

Comment: @Barmar: A `write(int fd, void* buf, size_t len)` system call doesn't care about `0` bytes.  Plus, there will happen to be one after the ASCII bytes anyway, in practice.  Out to the end of the page, in fact, which this program outputs since it copies the address to `x2` as the length as well as the pointer!  On Linux, a `write` that reads into unmapped pages will normally succeed as long as there's some valid data to write, and return with a length less than the requested size.  It returns `-EFAULT` if the first byte of the buffer is in an unmapped page.

Comment: What does `strace ./a.out` say?  It should decode the system calls you're making.  If it segfaults without showing any, then probably Jester's probably right that `svc #0` is necessary.  (IDK where you got the `#0x80` from; perhaps from i386 Linux where `int 0x80` is one way of making system calls?  In the old ARM on 32-bit ARM, non-zero immediates for `svc` were the call number, but that's apparently less convenient for the kernel to access.)

Comment: `mov x2, x1` is almost certainly the problem. How could you possibly expect that to put the length in `x2`?

Comment: `ldr x8, #64` is also wrong. That will load 8 bytes from an offset 0x40 bytes from the address of the ldr instruction. You probably meant `mov x8, #64`.

Comment: @Barmar: Wrong yes, but in practice in Linux a too-high length will just keep copying bytes to the destination fd until it hits an unmapped page, and then return the count of bytes actually written.  At most it would return `-EFAULT`, not actually deliver a SIGSEGV to user-space, so no, that doesn't explain crashing.  The OP should run it under `gdb ./a.out` to see which instruction faults.  (use `layout asm` or `layout reg`)

Comment: For what it's worth, I was not able to reproduce a segfault; the program as it stands (after fixing `hello_String` -> `hello_string`) just exits with no output.  The only way I can see that one could occur is if the code was less than 64 bytes from the end of a page, so that `ldr x8, #64` hit an unmapped page, but that seems unlikely.  So you might double check in case there are any differences between this code and what you are running.

Comment: @Jester: Linux ignores the immediate to `svc`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76567156/how-does-arm-svc-instruction-works/76569233#76569233, so that's not the issue.  Unlike x86 `int`, the immediate operand doesn't specify the vector; there is a single vector for all `svc` instructions, and the immediate operand is loaded into the syndrome register, but Linux doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the bugs were pointed out in comments, so I'll just collect them here:

- `ldr x8, #64`: This attempts to load a value into `x8` from memory, where the address is the program counter plus 64 bytes.   To put a small constant into a register, such as anything in the range `-65536..65536`, use `mov` as you did elsewhere: `mov x8, #64`.

  You might have been thinking of `ldr x8, =64`.  This does have the effect of putting the value `64` into `x8`, but in a less efficient way: it assembles the value `64` as a 64-bit integer into memory at some nearby location, and executes a memory load to retrieve it.  So it uses an extra 8 bytes of memory, and incurs the expense of a load from memory at runtime.  On the other hand, in `mov x8, #64`, the constant 64 is encoded directly into the instruction, and does not require any memory access (other than fetching the instruction for execution, which has to happen anyway).

  The `ldr =` method is useful if the constant is not one of the [set of values that can be encoded into an immediate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30904718/range-of-immediate-values-in-armv8-a64-assembly), such as an address.
- `adr x1, hello_String`: Typo here, should be `hello_string`.  Maybe it was already correct in your code and this is just a transcription error.  But if you use `hello_String` you get some linker errors that may be confusing.
- `mov x2, x1    // set register x2 with the string length`: No, it copies `x1`, which contains the *address* of `hello_string`, into `x2`, so that now they both contain the address.

  You could count the string length manually, and do `mov x2, #13`.  However, you can also get the assembler to do this work for you.  After the `.ascii` directive which assembles the string, you can use the `.` special symbol to get the current address (i.e. the next byte following the string) and subtract the starting address `hello_string`.  You can then define a symbol like `hello_len` with the result, and use it as the value to put in `x2`: `mov x2, #hello_len`.

  Note that all this arithmetic is done by the assembler, at build time; the resulting machine code contains only the same `mov x2, #13`  that you could have written by hand.  So it has no impact on runtime performance.

Here is a complete fixed version.

```
.global _start
.text
_start:

    // code for writing message to stdout
    mov x8, #64    // set register x8 with syscall number for write command
    mov x0, #1     // set register x0 with the file descriptor number
    adr x1, hello_string    // set register x1 with the address of the string
    mov x2, #hello_len    // set register x2 with the string length
    svc #0x80      // make supervisory call to the OS

    mov x8, #93    // set register x8 with syscall number for exit command
    mov x0, #0     // set register x0 with return value (=0 for no errors)
    svc #0x80      // make supervisory call to the OS

.data
hello_string: .ascii "Hello World!\n"
hello_len = . - hello_string
```

By the way, the value `#0x80` as the immediate operand to `svc` is not meaningful, as it is ignored by the kernel: see [How does arm svc instruction works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76567156/how-does-arm-svc-instruction-works/76569233#76569233).  It doesn't hurt anything, but any other value would also be fine, such as `#0`.  And this might avoid causing confusion for a reader of your code who wonders if there is special significance to `0x80`.

You could be thinking of x86-32 Linux, which uses the `int 0x80` instruction for a system call; in that case the immediate specifies which interrupt vector is to be called, and it does have to be `0x80` because that's the specific vector that Linux uses for system calls.  But again, that is entirely specific to 32-bit x86 code and is totally irrelevant to AArch64.

Comment: So why did this actually segfault?  In Linux, bad args to system calls result in error return values like `-EINVAL` or `-EFAULT`, not in delivering signals to the process.  If `ldr x8, #64` is actually PC-relative, it should be in the same page as the code and not fault, and AArch64 supports misaligned loads.  It didn't happen to load x8 = `__NR_kill` or some other system call that could deliver a signal, did it?  I'd expect `-ENOSYS` would be most likely.  The `_exit` system call number is set up with `mov` so should have worked.